# Error creating Uniswap V3 pool

Tags: uniswap, json-rpc, uniswapv3

Hi I have 2 ERC20 tokens deployed and I am trying to make a pool using Uniswap V3. When I deploy my `createUniswapPool.js` file I get an error. I have shared the error, createUniswapPool.js, and the expected output below

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at main (/Users/.../Desktop/.../uniswapv2-pug/createUniswapPool.js:22:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Code `createUniswapPool.js`:

````
const { ethers } = require('ethers')
const axios = require('axios')
require('dotenv').config()

const UNISWAP_V3_FACTORY_ADDRESS = '0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984'

const GOERLI_PROVIDER = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.INFURA_API_KEY)
const WALLET_ADDRESS = process.env.WALLET_ADDRESS
const WALLET_SECRET = process.env.WALLET_SECRET
const PUG_COIN_ADDRESS = '0xA4a0E3e8bBec6C56Ea121819324652bf0cCB32b9'
const POLY_COIN_ADDRESS = '0xBDfA1b5E41229B865037f001f5051ce47D075605'

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(WALLET_SECRET)
const connectedWallet = wallet. connect(GOERLI_PROVIDER)

async function main() {
// setup V3 Factory

const apiKey = 'MY_OWN_ETHERSCAN_KEY' // create account on etherscan and enter API key
const url = 'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${UNISWAP_V3_FACTORY_ADDRESS}&apikey=${apiKey}'
const res = await axios.get(url)
const abi = JSON.parse(res.data.result)

const factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(
    UNISWAP_V3_FACTORY_ADDRESS,
    abi,
    GOERLI_PROVIDER
)

// create the pool

const tx = await factoryContract.Contract.connect(connectedWallet).createPool(
    PUG_COIN_ADDRESS,
    POLY_COIN_ADDRESS,
    500 // can change fee 
)


const receipt = await tx.wait()
console.log('receipt', receipt)

//get pool address
const newPoolAddress = await factoryContract.getPool( 
     PUG_COIN_ADDRESS,
    POLY_COIN_ADDRESS,
    500 // BASIS POINT FEE - can change fee betweeb 500/1000 
)
console.log('newPoolAddress', newPoolAddress)



}

main() ```


Command I ran : ```node createUniswapPool.js```
````

Comment: From the error you can see problematic line is: `const abi = JSON.parse(res.data.result)`, I suspect you got an error message instead of contract ABI. Can you put a `console.log(res.data.result)` to the line before that to debug?